# False positive in S125 rule

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I run code analysis on my project and I see some occurrence of S125 but I think this is false positive.

My code

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// [Localized]
/// public class BaseController : Controller
/// {
/// }
/// 
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

Reported line is with { and this I think OK because line is code example for documentation.

Comment: I think you should file a bug report and see what they say :)

Comment: which version of the Sonarqube C# plugin are you using? Try the latest. In the IDE, SonarLint for Visual Studio doesn't report on your snippet.

Comment: I use sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar.

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma warning disable S125 
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// [Localized]
/// public class BaseController : Controller
/// {
/// }
/// 
/// </code>
/// </example>
#pragma warning restore
```

Try that. Source: http://www.programad.me/tag/sonarqube/